# Is it possible to move files to new branch after i commited them? Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, branch, branching-and-merging

I crated new directory in my project and because of rush forgot to create a new branch and  committed it to `default`. Is there any option now to move all files under this directory to new branch end remove them from default?

Comment: To make things worse i could not afford to wait for solution so there are few commits after that. Files in mentioned directory are not yet linked with any others...

Answer (score -1):

If you are still in `draft`, and that it is your last commit, you can get back to before the commit, by using this command:

```
hg strip --keep -r .
```

The `--keep` will keep the state of your directory intact, allowing you to change branch and re-commit your changeset. The `-r .` is to point it to where you are updated to, the changeset you wish to re-do.

Edit:
You can do that repeatedly if needed, to remove other changesets, but you will have to redo them all. If they are still in draft, there is no worries, but in public phase, it is another story.

Answer (score -1):

1. You must think **not** "files and directories", but "changeset(s), which contain *some changes*"
2. You can update to parent of <strike>tip</strike>first misbranched changest, create needed branch, commit (dummy) changeset and rebase changeset in the question into new branch